# Extracting data from columns unix

Tags: unix, sorting, awk, cygwin

I have files with multiple columns and I want to read values from a particular column. I can read a column using `awk{print $column_number}`.

Each file has different lengths of columns i.e. some might be 1000 entries long and others might be just 2 and so on. The entries themselves range from 1 digit up to a maximum of 5 digits. This is the same for all the files.

I want to count the range of the most repeated values. For example if the column reads:

```
5
93
201
2002
20003
20005
20087
31450
31451
31452
31458
52400
52428
```

then I want to store `31,400` as the most repeated value, then `20,000` and `52,000` as the second most and third most repeated values and so on. You can say that I am rounding up the values to see the most repeated numbers, if that makes sense. These values(the most repeated, the second most repeated) can be considered to be multiples of 100. So basically the code should look something like this:

`for f in ls path-to-the-files/*`

`do`

```
while read i

    do
    <do the operation to sort and store the values>
done
```

`done`

I'd appreciate help with this!

Comment: Are all ranges sequential chunks of 10,000?

Comment: No, they can be 11000, 67500, pretty much anything as long as that range is repeated often. Sorry should have mentioned that. I edited the 52,000 in the question.

Comment: I think you need to better define what a range is. 20000 and 52000 are not ranges, they are values.

Comment: I love solving problems using awk, but your "requirements" are really bad. You are really vague on what you are trying to do. What is a range? Is each column in each file processed separately or are they somehow linked?

Comment: I edited the question. I need to process on the same column in each file, but the length of this column will vary from file to file. I need to extract the range that has the most values. For example if there are 97 entries from 10,000 to 10,100 then 10,000 is what I want to obtain. I agree it's a little difficult to explain this with the proper choice of words.

Comment: You are going to have to define your range requirements very carefully.  Everything you've described is easy; building some sort of 'smart rounder' would be harder than the rest of what you've described by a factor of 100.

Comment: We can consider them to be multiples of 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/.\?.$//;s/^$/0/;s/.$/,&00/;s/^,/0,/' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr 
4 31,400
3 20,000
2 52,400
2 0,000
1 2,000
1 0,200
```

If you're not interested in the `,` format use:

```
sed 's/.\?.$//;s/$/00/;s/^00$/0/' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
  4 31400
  3 20000
  2 52400
  2 0
  1 2000
  1 200
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with my data. I am just getting `1's` for all the values i.e. it just shows that every value is present once. It's not counting the number of values in the observed ranges.

Comment: I tested using the data you provided and working in a linux environment. Maybe you have spaces either side of your data column. In which case put `s/^\s*//;s/\s*$//;` at the front of the first sed statement. Without knowledge of your data and your environment it's hard to advise.

Comment: I used this code on just the column and it works. I'll just spit out the column separately and run this to get the results. Unfortunately, some of my files are binary, any idea how i extract the columns from these?

Comment: I think you may have to revert to perl and use the  `unpack` command for binary files.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be wanting to count the number of values in each range of 100, 0..99, 100..199, 200..299, etc, and then find the largest such range.

You probably can do it in `awk` (and definitely in Python), but I'm going to use Perl.

I'm going to hard code the column number into the program; that can be made variable (e.g. an option on the command line) if need so be.  I chose column 3, counting from 0.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant colno => 3;

my %ranges;

while (<>)
{
    my(@fields) = split /\s+/;
    my($key) = int($fields[colno] / 100);
    $range{$key}++;
}

# The hash now contains the number of entries for each range that's present in the
# data.  Now we need to hack the data so that we can easily find the range(s) with
# the largest counts.
# Apply the Schwartzian Transform: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

my @results = map  { [$_->[0], $_->[1]]  }
              sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
              map  { [$_, $ranges{$_}]   }
                   keys %ranges;

# And print the results
foreach my $ref (reverse @results)
{
    printf "%5d = %d\n", $ref->[0] * 100, $ref->[1];
}
```

For your sample data (padded with three previous columns), the output is:

```
31400 = 4
20000 = 3
    0 = 2
52400 = 2
 2000 = 1
  200 = 1
```

The [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) is deep black magic.  It might not be necessary here, but it works.  (And yes, it is the first time I've used it.)

---

The Perl code was fun (and probably fairly fast), but if you don't have Perl on the machine, then you need an alternative.

```
awk '{value = int($3/100); print value*100;}' files |
sort |
uniq -c |
sort -nr
```

The `awk` code picks up column 3 (counting from 1, not 0!), divides the value by 100 and converts it to an integer, then prints the value multiplied by 100; this gives the grouping you want.  The remaining `sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` pipeline is a standard idiom for counting occurrences and sorting so that the most frequent appears first.  Actually, it is often better to leave the `r` out of the final sort so the last few lines of output are the most interesting.

Comment: what's `my %ranges` in your code. I need to first install the perl package for cygwin to try this out.

Comment: `my %ranges;` declares a hash which is subsequently referenced (in Perl's inimitable way) as `$ranges{$key}`, etc. Yes, you'd need Perl from Cygwin (or ActiveState) to test this. I've no idea whether you can do the Schwartzian Transform or its equivalent in `awk`; my gut feel is "no; it is a little too much for `awk`", but I may be selling it short. It was an interesting question. If you look at the canonical example on the Wikipedia page, you'll see the the first map listed above is slightly more complex than the sample listed there. But only slightly. It does look like line noise, though.

Comment: I have never worked with perl before, so i'm a little skeptical of switching to this, but will try this out tomorrow in the am. I'd probably run into some errors implementing the perl code in cygwin. will keep you posted! thank you!